# Php session are not being sent to other page by sending headers

Tags: php, web, web-development-server

```
Page1 
header("Location:Page2.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$NOFCHILDREN;


Page2 
  session_start();
    $name=$_SESSION['username'];
  echo $name;
```

On Page 2 it is showing error that
"Notice: Undefined index: username in "
Any solution to this problem??

Comment: Two things: Is `$NOFCHILDREN` defined? Have you tried to place `header(..)` at the end of Page1?

Comment: Yeah i did tried everything i could try but still facing this issue

Comment: That's strange @Usman Haider ... I cannot reproduce your error. It works perfect for me

Comment: In Page1 move your `session_start();` before the header call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely error source is:

## Session cookie not accepted

Check whether your browser accepts the session cookie. You can see it in Developer Tools in the Application tab (Chrome) or Storage tab (Firefox). If the PHPSESSID cookie changes on every request, the session cookie is not accepted. There might be details printed in the Console tab.

Always call [set_session_cookie_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) before any `session_start` call. This way you control the session cookie.

```
set_session_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 57600,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => 'example.com',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' => '', // or 'Strict' to make cross site attacks harder
]);
```

You can also set [INI options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path), though that is out-of-app configuration and I've found it easier to have the app handle its session cookie. Less to go wrong.

### Playing with the cookie

Using curl or some other HTTP request fiddling tool, you can confirm that it is indeed the browser interfering:

```sh
# Do a normal GET request to your first page, printing only headers.
$ curl -v -o /dev/null https://example.org/page1.php
[...]
< HTTP/2 200 
[...]
< set-cookie: PHPSESSID=xxx; expires=Mon, 04-Jan-2021 07:02:24 GMT; Max-Age=57600; path=/; domain=example.org; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None

# Do the second page request manually with the cookie copied from above output.
$ curl -b 'PHPSESSID=xxx' https://example.org/page2.php
```

## Other possible source

These are really just lucky guesses without access to your system:

- check whether the session file gets written correctly. [session_save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) gives you the directory. There are files in there whose names are equal to the PHPSESSID cookie value (again check Developer Tools or curl).

  - does it get written at all? If not: check permissions of the directory.
  - does it get written with expected data, but soon overwritten with empty/other data? There may be a race condition, though it sounds unlikely with your two simple scripts. Ajax call is a candidate for race condition.
- if you use any session handler other than `files`, there can be a whole slew of other error sources. Check via `ini_get('session.save_handler')` which handler you use.

Answer (score 0):

In page1, place your code as per below

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$NOFCHILDREN;
header("Location:Page2.php");
```

Your code redirects before the session sets the variable. It's not supposed to work this way. So add your redirect after the session set.